# Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace when running ng test

Tags: unit-testing, angular-cli

I am having this issue when trying to run ng test for a component that I've created.
I tried opening in integrated terminal, open a cmd terminal and try there and other things to but I always get that error.

src\apps\some-portal\src\app\created-component this would be the path.
Also tried to run from src and I have the same problem.

Comment: You have to run it from the root of your project, which is where the `package.json` is

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the same error :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.